# Apache Traffic Server cluster on Amazon Ec2 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, cluster-computing, apache-traffic-server

I am trying to setup Apache Traffic Server cluster on two Amazon EC2 instances.
I followed the steps from **http://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/en/latest/admin/cluster-howto.en.html** to set up the cluster. But when I give the following command 
`traffic_line -r proxy.process.cluster.nodes` still gives me value 1. But I am expecting value 2. I want to know whether is it possible to set up Apache Traffic Server cluster on EC2 instances? If possible could anyone let me know what are the other steps that need to be considered apart from the steps mentioned in above link.

Comment: The cluster peer discovery is happening with multicast.
Unfortunately, Amazon has multicast and broadcasts disabled. I am currently stuck on the same problem, will tell you, when I have a solution